# How to fix run issues in vscode for python scripts

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have been using vscode for only css and html and pycharm for python and lately I have switched to vscode also for my python scripts . I did all the necessary configurations and extensions installations I even installed code runner but so far I have not been able to properly run my python scripts without passing through the debug face when I click on the run button it still shows only the output from the previous run.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Are you saying that when you run the debug, it shows the previous results? Can you add the code you are working on, and the result you expect to see?

Comment: Have you read the [Run Python Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_run-python-code) tutorial from the VS Code docs?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to run the code like a Jupyter notebook. If you highlight code and press shift+enter it should turn on a python interpreter that runs the code in a new pane.